# Symfony : downgrade PHP version

Tags: symfony, composer-php

On my initial environment, I have a PHP 7.2.5.
But on the production environment, the version is 7.2.1.

I want to downgrade the version of PHP, but dependencies require 7.2.5 (the localhost:8000 is working fine).

```
{
    "name": "symfony/website-skeleton",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "MIT",
    "description": "A skeleton to start a new Symfony website",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "^3.1",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.1",
        "symfony/asset": "*",
        "symfony/console": "*",
        "symfony/dotenv": "*",
        "symfony/expression-language": "*",
        "symfony/flex": "^1.3.1",
        "symfony/form": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "*",
        "symfony/http-client": "*",
        "symfony/intl": "*",
        "symfony/mailer": "*",
        "symfony/mime": "*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1",
        "symfony/notifier": "*",
        "symfony/orm-pack": "*",
        "symfony/process": "*",
        "symfony/security-bundle": "5.2.*",
        "symfony/serializer-pack": "*",
        "symfony/string": "*",
        "symfony/translation": "*",
        "symfony/twig-pack": "*",
        "symfony/validator": "*",
        "symfony/web-link": "*",
        "symfony/yaml": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "^3.4",
        "symfony/debug-pack": "*",
        "symfony/maker-bundle": "^1.0",
        "symfony/profiler-pack": "*",
        "symfony/test-pack": "*"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": {
            "*": "dist"
        },
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "replace": {
        "symfony/polyfill-ctype": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-iconv": "*",
        "symfony/polyfill-php72": "*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "auto-scripts": {
            "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
            "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
        },
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@auto-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "conflict": {
        "symfony/symfony": "*"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this error ? For now, if I don't use any **composer** command, it's fine, but I guess if I use any **composer require** I'll have an error due to PHP version ?

How can I downgrade all dependencies at the same time than php version ?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to make this work? Which parts of that error message are unclear to you?

Comment: I've started a projet In 7.2.5, I need to 7.2.1. I didn't said the message way unclear, the message is perfectly clear. I need to downgrade and the php version to 7.2.1 and all the dependencies directly

Comment: And what have you tried to do this? Like: have you checked my answer below?

Comment: Also: be warned that PHP 7.2 is no longer supported. No bugs are fixed any longer. The version 7.2.1 is more than two years old, and even if you insist to use PHP 7.2 on your production system, you should upgrade it to v7.2.34 to use a bug-free version

Answer (score 0):

Symfony 5.2 requires PHP 7.2.5, so there is no way that you can use Symfony 5.2 with any lower PHP version. The latest Symfony version compatible with PHP 7.2.1 is v4.4.

To perform the downgrade of Symfony, this is the part you need to check:

```
    "extra": {
        "symfony": {
            "allow-contrib": false,
            "require": "5.2.*"
        }
    }
```

It specifically asks `symfony/flex` to use Symfony 5.2. If you want to downgrade Symfony, edit the version here and run `composer update`.

---

Keep in mind that this works best when **all** Symfony components are required without any specific version constraint. `symfony/security-bundle` should be used with a `*` requirement, as all other components

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know this version was buggy. I'll try to switch to a more stable/maintened version

Comment: What do you mean by "buggy"?

Comment: "bug-free version" doesn't mean "has bug" ? (sorry i'm french)

Comment: Yes, that's what it means - but I haven't said that any version **is** in fact buggy